# Not working file attachment with Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, file, laravel-5

I need attach some file and save to the table like .pdf and .jpeg using form submition in laravel 5.7
this is my file attach form group

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">CV</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="file">
</div>
</div>
```

and controller is like this,

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
                $datas = New Data;
        $datas->job = $request->input('job');
        $datas->name = $request->input('name');
        $datas->expe = $request->input('exp');
        $datas->salary = $request->input('salary');
        $datas->file = $request->input('file');
        $datas->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Job has been saved sucessfully');

    }
```

but when I submit form to save file following error massage is occured
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'file' cannot be null`
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: _how can I fix this problem?..._ Make the column to be nullable? Or check if there is a file in your request

Comment: there is file in my request

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/uploading-images-and-storing-in-database Check if this will help you.

Comment: no any solutions here